# How to create "remove all" / "remove current image" button?

Tags: php, sql, database, sql-delete

So right now I have a page list of photos grabbed from my database and the code looks like this:

```
<?php
require_once 'favorites.php';
if (isset($_GET["fileName"])) {
    $fileName = $_GET["fileName"];
    addToFavorites($fileName);

}

if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    $favorites = getFavorites();
    if (count($favorites) > 0) {
        ?> <ul class="ul-favorite"> <?php
            foreach ($favorites as $f) {
                echo '<img class="displayPic" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/assignment1_web2/square150/' . $f->Path . '">';
                echo '<button type="button">X</button> &emsp;';
                }
                ?>
           </ul>
           <button class="button">Remove All</button>
```

Each image will have a little button "X" next to it and at the end of the list theres a "remove all" button.

How should I code it so that each "X" removes that specific image from the database and the "remove all" removes all from database?

My helper functions:

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "travel");
function getFavorites(){
    global $conn;
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $sql = "Select * from favorites, imagedetails where UserEmail='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $email)."' and favorites.ImageID=imagedetails.ImageID";
    $arr = array();
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while(($row= mysqli_fetch_object($result))!=null){
        array_push($arr, $row);
    }
    return $arr;
}
function addToFavorites($fileName)
{
    global $conn;
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $imageId = $_GET["id"];

    $sql = "insert into favorites set UserEmail='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $email)."', ImageID=".$imageId;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Do I have to make new php pages like removeSelected.php and removeAll.php with code to remove from database and then link those pages to the buttons? How would I do all of that? Thanks!